# Structuring data correctly in a local file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a data file for a mock up. I have a cityData object with cities inside of it. Unfortunately I have set them up to read as arrays incorrectly. So now when I call the data into the 'city' UI file it's not found. Actually looks like each item has 4 arrays inside of them. My goal is to call in cityData and filter through to match the city name to the routh path name.

City UI file.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { cityData } from "../api/dummydata";

export default function service() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const city = router.asPath.replace("/", "").replace("%20", " ")
  const data = cityData
  //also tried   const data = cityData.Object.keys(city) - This will tell me 
  Object does not exist type// 

  return ()
}
```

cityData returns as such:

```
 Object 
   austin: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   dallas: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   el_paso: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   galveston: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   houston: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   san_antonio: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Data file:

```
export const cityData = {
    austin: [
      {details:""},
      {sights: []},
      {more_details:""},
      {image: ""}
    ],
    dallas: [
      {details:""},
      {sights: []},
      {more_details:""},
      {image:"../assets/dallas.jpg"}
    ],
    el_paso: [ 
      {details:""},
      {sights: []},
      {more_details:""},
      {image:"../assets/el-paso-texas.jpg"}
    ],
    galveston:  [
      {details:""},
      {sights: []},
      {more_details:""},
      {image:"../assets/galveston-island.jpg"}
    ],
    houston: [
      {details:""},
      {sights: []},
      {more_details:""},
      {image:"../assets/houston.jpg"}
    ],
    san_antonio: [
      {details:""},
      {sights: []},
      {more_details:""},
      {image:"../assets/san_antonio.jpg"}
    ],
  }
```

How can I structure cityData correctly so that I can filter cityData.filter((x) => x.name = city) or bring back the Object.keys()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly (correct me if am wrong) what you want is to simplify the structure of your object and return only the data of the city which matches the route path name, which is right now an object of objects where each object has one array and each array has multiple objects, Now this is wrong because filter function only works on array and your cityData is an object so we should first convert it to array and then give a key to each city like name:'austin', this way it will be easy to lookup, Now I am assuming that this CityData is something that you made yourself it is not being fetched or created via code.

So to convert this structure in a way so that you can use - `cityData.filter((x) => x.name = city)`
You can restructure your data something like this

```js
const cityData = [{
    name: 'austin',
    details: "",
    sights: [],
    more_details: "",
    image: "",
  },
  {
    name: 'dallas',
    details: "",
    sights: [],
    more_details: "",
    image: "../assets/dallas.jpg",
  },
];

const filteredCities = cityData.filter((city) => {
  if (city.name == 'austin') {
    return true
  }
});
console.log(filteredCities);
```

This will return an array that will contain only the data of Austin,
you can update this snippet to read data from the city variable instead of hardcoding it in the filter function.

Comment: Yes thank you. Now it seems so obvious to arrange the structure this way!  Worked as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is for it to be an array of objects rather than object of objects, so from:

```
const cityData = {
    austin: [
      {details:""},
      {sights: []},
      {more_details:""},
      {image: ""}
    ],
    ...
}
```

to:

```
const cityData = [
  { 
    name: austin,
    data: [
      {details:""},
      {sights: []},
      {more_details:""},
      {image: ""}
    ],
  },
  ...
]
```

To do that, you can iterate over the keys as you have tried:

```
const cityDataAsArray = Object.keys(cityData).map((key) => {
  const data = cityData[key];
  const item = {
    name: key,
    data: data,
  };
  return item;
});
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-cb2n6m?file=index.js)

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
  const obj = {}
  obj.name = key;
  value.forEach(item => Object.assign(obj, item))
  return obj
})
/*
newData = [
  {
     name: "austin",
     details:"",
     sights: [],
     more_details:"",
     image: ""
  }, 
  ...
]
*/
```